# How to concatenate functions and strings

Tags: concatenation

I have

```
f[x_]=Log[1+x]

g[x_]=TraditionalForm[Series[f[x], {x, 0, 4}]]
```

Is there a way to get the answer to print out as

```
Ln(1+x) = x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+O(x^5)
```

I've tried to use `StringJoin` but this doesn't seem to work

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: why doesn't `Ln[1 + x] == Series[f[x], {x, 0, 4}] // TraditionalForm` work for you?

Comment: Because when I go change f[x] then it doesn't automatically update the left hand side of the answer

Comment: `f[x] == Series[f[x], {x, 0, 4}] // TraditionalForm` ?

Comment: How do I get the mathematica formatting on the question. I hope what I've typed in the question isn't misleading, I do want the answer to appear in traditional form, it's just that when I copied and pasted from mathematica it came out this way

Comment: @user42582 Oh man, that works :P Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

```
f[x] == Series[f[x], {x, 0, 4}] // TraditionalForm
```

does the trick.

On a more general note, one could also use:

```
pretty[f_, x_, n_] := Module[{},
 f[x] == Series[f[x], {x, 0, n}] // TraditionalForm
]
```

like so:

```
pretty[f,x,4]
```

to get the desired output.

Note, that there is no concatenation needed. Furthermore, *Mathematica* does not need to splice together *functions* and *strings* (even though it could have done, easily). See [TraditionalForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) from *Wolfram Language* reference guide.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

How do you get the mathematica like formatting

Comment: you're welcome; please give an example of what you mean by "mathematica-like formating"; would https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help help out?

Comment: That definitely helps. What I meant was formatting the text so it looks like mathematica code rather than plain text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
StringJoin[{ToString[f[x]], " = ", ToString[g[x]]}]
```

> $Log[1+x] = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+O\left(x^5\right)$